# How to use apply or map to change the content of a dataframe based on the range and contents given by another, specially if the ranges rave overlap

Tags: r, dictionary, apply

I recently asked the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425315/how-to-use-apply-to-change-the-elements-of-one-dataframe-based-in-the-columns-of). Basically I wanted to modify a data frame based on the ranges given by another one. lets take `df2` as `df2 <- data.frame(b=c(7,25,31,44),e=c(11,27,36,48),n=c('a','b','c','d'))` resulting in

```
   b  e n
1  7 11 a
2 25 27 b
3 31 36 c
4 44 48 d
```

I need data frame column name of `df1` to be 'a' between 7 and 11, 'b' between 15 and 27 and so forth. I decide to create a logical vector with the positions that needed change, that in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425315/how-to-use-apply-to-change-the-elements-of-one-dataframe-based-in-the-columns-of) Ronak Shah helped me with

```
logint <- rep(FALSE,50)
logint[unlist(Map(`:`, df$b, df$e))] <- TRUE
```

I then proceeded to create a vector with the repeated letter in the adequate length with

```
nam <- unlist(apply(df2[,c('b','e','n')],1, function(x){return(rep(x['n'],as.numeric(x['e'])-as.numeric(x['b'])+1))}))
```

That I then use to set the correct values in df1 with

```
df1 <- data.frame(pos=rep(0,50),name=NA)
df1[logint,'pos'] <- 1
df1[logint,'name'] <- nam
```

This goes fine until there is overlap in the columns of `df2`, say

`df2 <- data.frame(b=c(7,25,31,44),e=c(11,27,46,48),n=c('a','b','c','d'))`

In this case the nam vector gets too long. How can I make this happen? For practical reasons it doesn't matter if the elements 44 to 46 are named 'c' or 'd' in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `mapply` the map like this:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(b = c(7, 25, 31, 44), e = c(11, 27, 46, 48), n = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
logint <- rep(FALSE, 50)
newcol <- character(max(df2$e))
mapply(function(x, y) {newcol[x] <<- as.character(y)}, Map(`:`, df2$b, df2$e), df2$n)
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
newcol
#>  [1] ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "" 
#> [20] ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "b" "b" "b" ""  ""  ""  "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c"
#> [39] "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d" "d"
```

The later entries overwrite the earlier entries in this case.

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>